# How to select records where two fields are unique

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+
| Contract_ID |   Name   |   Username    |  Password  |
+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+
|    12345671 | Facebook | john.doe      | password   |
|    12345672 | Google   | john.doe      | password   |
|    12345673 | Apple    | martha.malone | doodlebear |
|    12345674 | Samsung  | jimmy47       | parkour445 |
|    12345675 | HTC      | rick.grimes   | simpsons33 |
+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+
```

I'd like to select only records where there is a one to one ratio between username/password combination and contract id. In this case, that would mean I'd like to select the 3rd, 4th and 5th records in this table.

I've tried different combinations of the DISTINCT keyword but that doesn't seem to be the correct route to go. Is there a query that can return this information?

As a sort of bonus question: is there a query that can produce the opposite results (ie. only records where there is  greater than 1 to 1 ratio between contract ids and username/password combination)?

Comment: So you want to select all Contract_ID where the username and password combination are unique?

Comment: If the first entry was john.doe and password1234, would you want the query to return all the results in the table?

Comment: Yes. Some of the usernames and/or passwords are not unique. I'm just looking for unique combinations of the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the GROUP BY clause together with the HAVING clause, for example:

```
SELECT Username, Password FROM Table
GROUP BY Username, Password
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

The opposite is:

```
SELECT Username, Password FROM Table
GROUP BY Username, Password
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: The first query works perfectly, thank you. I want to also return the Contract_ID so I added that to both queries. However, when I run the second query it doesn't return all records. By that I mean that in the example used in the question, I would want it to return two rows, the first two in the table. Instead, it returns only one result, the first row.

Comment: MySQL allows you to add columns to your SELECT list, that are not in your GROUP BY clause. Be aware that the results may be unpredictable if there's more than one row in each group. This is not a problem when HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 is in effect, of course.

Comment: You could add `GROUP_CONCAT(Contract_id) as contract_ids` to the `SELECT` of the second statement to get a list of the contract_ids with the same username and password.

Comment: Is there a way then where I can select the difference between all records in the table and the unique records given in your first query?

Answer (score 0):

Group by (Name, Password) doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Very naughty way of doing it,not good at all, but it works:

```
    select distinct
    least(col1, col2) as value1
  , greatest(col1, col2) as value2
from yourtable
```